# JSON error when i parse with json.org

Tags: java, json, parsing

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {


        String s = "{paramsArray: [\"first\", 100],"
                + "paramsObj: {one: \"two\", three: \"four\"},"
                + "paramsStr: \"some string\"}";

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object ob = parser.parse(s);
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) ob;
        System.out.println(obj.get("paramsStr"));


    }

}
```

---

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (p) at position 1.
at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
at Main.main(Main.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120) `
```

Comment: The key values in the objects need to be in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Your json is not valid.

The `paramsArray`,`paramsObj`,`one`,`three` and `paramsStr` should be wrapped beetween double quotes (a valid JSON has keys and values both wrapped).

```
String s = "{\"paramsArray\": [\"first\", 100],"
            + "\"paramsObj\": {\"one\": \"two\", \"three\": \"four\"},"
            + "\"paramsStr\": \"some string\"}";
```

Try a JSON validator like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
"{ 'paramsArray': ['first', '100']," + 
  "'paramsObj': { 'one':   'two'," +
                   "'three': 'four'}," +
  "'paramsStr': 'some string'}"
```

Use single quotes inside double ones to increase readability like so...

Comment: Although some parsers may accept single quotes, the [JSON specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) specifically says that names, which are string values, need to be enclosed in double quotes `"`.